# bootstrap 4.1 border table

Tags: bootstrap4

задача сделать скругленный бордер у тела таблицы, шапка таблицы вообще без бордера.

```
 <table class="table custom-modal-table w-100 mb-0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <div class="card">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </div>
        </table>
```

при таком варианте ломются колонки друг относительно друга Thead/tbody

так вычитал что есть возможность кастомизации стилей бутстрапа.  занесением нужных стилей в файл _custom.scss, но не нашёл куда его засунуть в корне проекта?

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, то у bootstrap это:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        ....
    </table>
</div>
```

Есть такой пример, без bootstrap:

```css
#RoundedTable {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#RoundedTable td, #RoundedTable th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table id="RoundedTable">
  <tr><th>Table header</th><th>Another header cell</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Table cell...</td><td>More data...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table cell...</td><td>More data...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table cell...</td><td>More data...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table cell...</td><td>More data...</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: <div class="panel panel-default">  это бутсрап версии 3. Ещё раз повторюсь. Круглый бордер нужен вокруг tbody, thead   без бордера совсем.  П.С. без бутстрапа сделал быстро, заказчик хочет на бутстрапе.

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили, да точно )))